# Play youtube auto-generated subtitles offline to show word-by-word exactly like youtube player

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, youtube, subtitles, daum-pot-player

How to play youtube auto-generated **word-by-word** subtitles offline so that they're shown *word-by-word,* not ***sentence-by-sentence***?

---

I'm able to download auto-generated subtitles using youtube-dl:

`youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhpuT8UNWCyDZsF-ePrHuTW4vP3egLNPe --skip-download --write-auto-sub --sub-lang en -o "%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s`

 I get .vtt subtitles with words being time-stamped, here's a snippet example:

```
WEBVTT
Kind: captions
Language: en
Style:
::cue(c.colorCCCCCC) { color: rgb(204,204,204);
 }
::cue(c.colorE5E5E5) { color: rgb(229,229,229);
 }
##

00:00:00.740 --> 00:00:06.180 align:start position:19%
hey<00:00:01.740><c> everybody</c><c.colorCCCCCC><00:00:02.159><c> today</c><00:00:02.460><c> we're</c></c><c.colorE5E5E5><00:00:02.970><c> gonna</c><00:00:03.090><c> make</c><00:00:04.020><c> a</c></c>

00:00:04.080 --> 00:00:08.400 align:start position:19%
brief<c.colorE5E5E5><00:00:04.410><c> introduction</c><00:00:05.069><c> and</c><00:00:05.400><c> look</c><00:00:05.879><c> at</c><00:00:05.970><c> some</c><00:00:06.120><c> of</c></c>

00:00:06.180 --> 00:00:09.660 align:start position:19%
the<00:00:06.270><c> fundamental</c><c.colorE5E5E5><00:00:06.450><c> concepts</c><00:00:07.200><c> moving</c><00:00:08.040><c> forward</c></c>

00:00:08.400 --> 00:00:11.580 align:start position:19%
that<c.colorE5E5E5><00:00:08.490><c> we're</c></c><c.colorCCCCCC><00:00:08.639><c> gonna</c><00:00:08.730><c> cover</c><00:00:08.940><c> in</c><00:00:09.090><c> the</c><00:00:09.150><c> course</c><00:00:09.300><c> I'm</c></c>

00:00:09.660 --> 00:00:15.299 align:start position:19%
Michele<00:00:10.320><c> Behar</c><c.colorCCCCCC><00:00:10.559><c> B's</c></c><c.colorE5E5E5><00:00:10.710><c> and</c><00:00:11.070><c> I'm</c></c><c.colorCCCCCC><00:00:11.250><c> Vivek</c></c>
```

The nearest software usage to what I'm looking for is [Potplayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/). But it's problem with me is that it displays the whole sentence first, then go on styling word by word which is great. But I need it displayed word by word as on the Youtube player.

---

Another problem with PotPlayer is that it styles words with very slight difference in colors, so that it's hard to see the words that are spoken or not specially on white background. I tried changing the colors from the .vtt file itself but nothing changes, it seems that PotPlayer styling settings overrule.

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution I've provided for this issue, you can download this tool: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p4NEhGdg1DvmmOen3sF_Ppa8mGs36Fqu/view?usp=sharing

Once double clicked, it will automatically convert the .vtt auto-generated caption to a .srt subtitle file, where words appear word-by-word.

I wrote this tool because I have emailed the developer of PotPlayer, and asked him if he could kindly add an option for disable displaying the remaining part of .vtt caption, but his response is simply: "No, I don't want it~ So please don't say it again~"

Hope this tool might help!